# Displaying different values from same table and column after comparing

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, label, local-database

```
public partial class UserProfile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static int _userId = 0 ;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FoB;

        if (Session["user"] != null)
        {
            _userId = DataManager.GetUserId(Session["user"].ToString());
        }
        string connection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from dbo.Rating where UserID=_userId", conn);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        conn.Open();
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
            FoB = reader["GenreID"].ToString();
        if(FoB=="1" )
        {
            FB.Text = reader["RatingValue"].ToString();
        };

            }
            while (reader.HasRows);

            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I have a table named `rating`. It has 4 columns

```
RatingId, UserID, GenreID,Rating value
```

I want to display rating value on a label based on the current user logged in and different rating value against different Genres. `UserID` and `GenreID` are foreign keys from table `Genre` and `User`.

**Edit (comment)**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rating] ( 
  [RatingID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, 
  [UserID] INT NULL, [GenreID] INT NOT NULL, 
  [RatingValue] INT NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RatingID] ASC), 
  CONSTRAINT [FK_Rating_Genre] FOREIGN KEY ([GenreID]) 
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Genre] ([GenreID]) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
  CONSTRAINT [FK_Rating_User] FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) 
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserID]) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE );
```

I want to show 8 different rating values of 8 different genres by 1 single current user.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to map your label to different columns, based on another, discriminating column:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
using (var comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from dbo.Rating where UserID=@userId", conn))
{
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", _userId);
    conn.Open();
    using (var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows && reader.Read())
        {
            FB.Text = reader["GenreID"].ToString() == "1"
               ? reader["RatingValue"].ToString();
               : reader["SomeOtherColumn"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

If one or more of the columns to be mapped reside in another table other than `Rating`, you'll need to join to that table - we'll need to see your table structures to help you.

**Edit, re displaying 8 Genres**

I've assumed the User and Genre tables both have a column `Name` - join to these tables to look up the rating. The `GROUP and MAX` will eliminate any cases where the same user has more than one rating in the same Genre (switch the `MAX` to `AVG` or `MIN` if you need otherwise). Top 8 will restrict the genres. So adjust the Sql like so:

```
SELECT TOP 8 u.Name AS UserName, g.Name as GenreName, MAX(r.RatingValue) AS TopRating
FROM dbo.Rating r
  INNER JOIN dbo.[User] u
    ON r.UserId = u.UserID
  INNER JOIN dbo.[Genre] g
    ON r.GenreID = g.GenreID
WHERE UserID=@userId
GROUP BY u.Name, g.Name
ORDER BY g.Name;
```

Now, for user interface, you won't be able to display a table in a single label. The easiest would simply be to bind the result of the reader directly to a new `GridView` control on your WebForm

```
    using (var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            gridView.DataSource = reader;
            gridView.DataBind();            
        }
    }
```

This will show a table with 3 columns matching the selected columns, and and up to 8 rows.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rating] (
    [RatingID]    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID]      INT NULL,
    [GenreID]     INT NOT NULL,
    [RatingValue] INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RatingID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Rating_Genre] FOREIGN KEY ([GenreID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Genre] ([GenreID]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Rating_User] FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserID]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
 I want to show 8 different rating values of 8 different genres by 1 single current user

Comment: I've pasted your comment into your question and have updated my answer. I'm assuming Sql Server as the database - please add the Sql-Server OR MySql OR Oracle tags to your question as applicable.

Comment: Problem of user value is solved.
Now can you please guide how rating value can be displayed according to genre id?

Comment: I incorrectly gave the column names the same name - updated the Sql with aliases. You'll also need to show the Genre table so we can use the correct column name.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Genre] (
    [GenreID]   INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [GenreType] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([GenreID] ASC)
);
There are 8 genres
This is table of user
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [UserID]   INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FullName] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Email]    VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Photo]    IMAGE        NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC)
);

also i want to show data at 8 different labels , not on single gridview
Thank you for your time :)